# send jsonobject to server but php can not covert json object to array

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

i send json object to server with volley and get data in server, but i can not convert jason object to array in php and my code dose not work

```js
    {
 "type": "get_new_products",
 "city": "abhar",
 "page": 0
}
```

php code

```
<?php
$get_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($get_post, true);
$content_type = $post_data['type'];
echo $content_type; ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that you receive data at all? With `echo $get_post;` for example.

Comment: There's not really a whole question here

Comment: yes i get data $get_post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the encoding. Try using `utf8_decode()`.

```
$jsonString = '{"type": "get_new_products","city": "abhar","page": 0}';
$decodedJson = utf8_decode($jsonString);

// Second parameter must be true to output an array
$jsonArray = json_decode($decodedJson, true);

// Error handling
if (json_last_error()) {
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo 'No errors';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo 'Maximum stack depth exceeded';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo 'Underflow or the modes mismatch';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo 'Unexpected control character found';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo 'Syntax error, malformed JSON';
            break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Unknown error';
            break;
    }
}

// Output values
echo "The type is: ".$jsonArray['type']."\n";
echo "The city is: ".$jsonArray['city']."\n";
```

#### This will output

```
The type is: get_new_products
The city is: abhar
The page is: 0

echo "The page is: ".$jsonArray['page']."\n";
```

The error handling has been copied from the PHP.net manual.

#### Resources

- [utf8_decode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)
- [json_last_error() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: that`s echo no errors but didnt worked and i coudent get content from jsonobject

Comment: @itstudent Take another look at my answer. I've edited it slightly.

Comment: This code is working without problem , just i used <br> inested of \n

Comment: @itstudent If my answer answered your question, you can mark this as the best answer by clicking the button to the left of the answer.

Comment: I replace $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input'); and sent jsonobject with postMan to php and that worked correctly but do not echo 'No errors';